Why is my world texture not appearing?
So, I am trying to apply a texture to my world but it is not appearing. It is appearing on the cup's shadows though. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?


I fixed it by going to Render > Film and unchecking Transparent.

Transparent is turned off by default, so you have to deliberately turn it on. Why did you turn it on if you want to see the background or if you don't know what effect it has?
